Hodge structure and Complex Structure of Riemann surfaces
Let $\Sigma$ be a closed oriented $2$-dimensional topological manifold of genus $g$. We know $H^1(\Sigma,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq H_1(\Sigma,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$. Fix a set of $2g$ 1-cycles
$$
\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_g, b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_g\}
$$
that generate $H_1$ with $$(a_i, b_j) = \delta_{i,j},\quad (a_i, a_j) = (b_i, b_j) = 0.$$
I am interested in parametrizing all complex structures on $\Sigma$ (up to biholomorphism) in terms of Hodge structure. The same parametrization problem is known to correspond to the problem of certain Riemannian metrics on it [1], a direction that I don't want to go into here.
Any complex structure $c$ for $\Sigma$ makes it a complex manifold, so we have a Hodge decomposition
$$\mathbb{C}\langle[a_1],\ldots, [b_g]\rangle = H^1(\Sigma, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{C} = H^{1,0}(\Sigma) \oplus H^{0,1}(\Sigma),$$
each piece has complex dimension $g$.
Question

How do we use this decomposition to recover $c$ up to biholomorphism?

Does any decomposition of $\mathbb{C}\langle[a_1],\ldots, [b_g]\rangle$ into two $g$-dimensional subspace arise from some complex structure?


[1] A primer on mapping class groups, by Farb and Margalit.

You might want to take a look at Torelli's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torelli_theorem
